# The development client (com.reactnative02) for this project is not installed. Please build and install the client on the device first

Tags: reactjs, react-native, android-studio, react-redux

I am getting the above error when previewing the react app on an android studio simulator. Please help. Here is the error:

> "CommandError: The development client (com.reactnative02) for this
> project is not installed. Please build and install the client on the
> device first."

Answer (score 18):

I was facing the same issue and below commands helped me to resolve it. Hope works for you as well.
Firstly close your Metro Bundler and emulator, then try:

```
expo run:android
```

If it doesn't help go with:

```
npx react-native run-android
```

Answer (score 8):

probably you are tring to use development build.

first start your expo app (-c for clear cache)

```
npx expo start -c
```

then press `s` (for switch to expo go)

now you can press `a` (for run android emulator)

*alternative:*

you can use `--go` option for start with expo go

```
npx expo start --go
```

*NOTE*

Same libraries not work on expo go and require development build. If you are using library like this first you must create a development build. (https://docs.expo.dev/develop/development-builds/create-a-build/)

Answer (score 6):

`expo start --android` worked for me. This is assuming you're using expo of course.

Answer (score 2):

Uninstall the application via adb:

```
adb uninstall com.reactnative02
```

Comment: Whis worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

if you are on expo and you are trying to build your app locally then you get this error follow the step below

1. run this command `npx expo run:android`
   this will create a new android folder in your project , don't panic your app is still on Expo
2. in the android folder ADD new file name it `local.properties` so in this new file paste this
   `sdk.dir = C:\\Users\\PC-USER\\AppData\\Local\\Android\\sdk` , replace PC-USER with your PC user name , then save it
3. stop the running process in the command line with CTRL C , then run this command again `npx expo run:android`.

thanks this is what works for me, it will surely work for you

Answer (score 0):

In my case (expo), it was because my android phone was plugged when I pressed a to start the emulator so it was trying to run it on my phone which doesn't have the development build.

So I just unplugged my phone from the PC and did

```
npx expo start --dev-client
```

Answer (score 0):

This happens when trying to build with EAS dependency. It's actually the switch of build types.

You can solve this by just running

> **npm start**

and then

> **press s | switch to development build**.

It's done.

(Reseting caching maybe required)